# Host a Docker container in Azure and have it active during a specific period of the day?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, automated-tests, containers

I would like to have a docker container active only during certain time's in the day so that a Test Automation can run? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is **possible**. [Cronjobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) is designed to run a job periodically on a given schedule, written in Cron format. A [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) creates one or more Pods and will continue to retry execution of the Pods until a specified number of them successfully terminate.

To run your automation tests

- You should create a Cronjob definition
- Set the cron timer
- Call your CMD

Here is a sample Hello Wordl example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much information beside running and stopping a container.  One of the simplest way is to use the Docker CLI to run an instance of your container in Azure Container Instances.  You create and use a context for Azure and then, using docker run will create an ACI and run your container in Azure.

```
docker login azure
docker context create aci myacicontext
docker context use myacicontext
docker run -p 80:80 [yourImage]
docker rm [instanceName]
```

Ref: https://www.docker.com/blog/running-a-container-in-aci-with-docker-desktop-edge/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/quickstart-docker-cli

Comment: I want to be able to run a container between 5-8pm and turn it off automatically after that as I dont need it during the rest of the day, because what's in the container isn't a web application, I dont think Azure would wake it up automatically if it went to sleep